# How to connect to a broker API using sockets and Java?

Tags: java, json, api, sockets, trading

I've been trying to connect to the XTB API and I can't seem to make it work.
I have zero experience with sockets and I'm learning on the go. I'm trying to send the JSON object and I'm expecting some kind of response either a success message or an error but I don't get anything. I don't even know if I'm doing it right.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String host = "xapi.xtb.com";
    int port = 5112;
    Socket s;
    try {
        JSONObject main = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
        main.put("command", "login");
        user.put("userId", "MY_ID");
        user.put("password", "MY_PSSWD");
        main.put("arguments", user);
        
        s = new Socket(host, port);
        SocketAddress a;
        
        a = new InetSocketAddress("xapi.xtb.com", 5112);
        
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        
        out.write(main.toString());
        String response = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(response);
        in.close();
        out.close();
        
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are using BufferedWriter so try `out.flush();` otherwise your code doesn't actually send anything. Or don't use BufferedWriter.

Comment: It returns NULL every time, i cant find anyone on the internet that tried connecting to a broker api using Java and sockets ... :/

Comment: What returns null?

Answer (score 1):

I only managed to get their WebSocket endpoints to work. That, in addition to the fact that their entire API documentation contains WebSocket commands only, makes me think they expect users to connect that way.

I can't help you with Java, but the algorithm is as follows:

**1. Define connection**

Get a WebSocket client library / package. Usually first thing you do is to instantiate an object using the wss://... address as parameter. Don't issue the connect command at this stage.

**2. Define event handlers**

Most WebSocket clients dispatch events which you need to handle in your code.

First event will typically be 'open' and it will be fired once the connection is established. Every message coming from server will fire a 'message' event. You need to write handlers for the 'onOpen' and 'onMessage' events (however the naming convention may be) which will execute your code's logic.

Typically there will be a 'send' command in your WebSocket package that you can use to send messages to the server. Use the command described in the documentation as payload of the send command:

```
// pseudocode

ws.send({ 
  "command":"login",
  "arguments": {
    "userId":"1000",
    "password":"PASSWORD"
  }
})
```

**3. Connect**

Once the event handlers are defined, you can issue the 'connect' command.

Good luck with your trading. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

maybe im very, very, very too late but... I have been playing with your example.

You are getting null, because the connection is plain http.

To fix it, you need to change:

```
import java.net.Socket;
```

to

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
```

And then, when creating the socket...

instead of

```
Socket s
s = new Socket(host, port);
```

You must put this:

```
 SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
 SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
```

Also, after out.write.... add

```
    out.flush();
```

And you are done

Why? in the xtb api docs they said this:

All servers use SSL connection.

And after messing a bit with wireshark, I found that the JSON was sent in plain text...

You may have already found it before, because this question is old, but it remains here in case someone else has the problem